# How can I implement multiple lists in Schema.org using JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am implementing Schema.org structured data into my magazine-style website and have a couple of concerns regarding the use of multiple lists.

I have two sections on my home page: 'Most Recent' and 'Most Popular'. Both sections contain five mini-articles each. I have considered both of these sections as 'lists'. This is an example of one section - the other is identical apart from the articles, obviously:

[image]

This is my Schema JSON-LD. I have cut this sample short at `...` for the sake of keeping the sample easily readable and have removed domains/names, etc. So far, I have only added the five articles from 'Most Recent' to this `ItemList` and testing it using Google's Structured Data Testing Tool returns zero warnings and zero errors:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "ItemList",
        "numberOfItems": "5",
        "itemListOrder": "Descending",
        "itemListElement": [
            {
                "@type": "Article",
                "position": "1",
                "mainEntityOfPage": {
                    "@type": "WebPage",
                    "@id": "/motoring/audi-launches-2019-sq8-tdi/"
                },
                "articleSection": "Motoring",
                "headline": "Audi launches 2019 SQ8 TDI",
                "datePublished": "2019-09-01",
                "dateModified": "2019-09-01",
                "image": "/content/uploads/2019/08/2019-audi-sq8-tdi-001-800.jpg",
                "url": "/motoring/audi-launches-2019-sq8-tdi/",
                "author": "The Author",
                "publisher": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "Company Name",
                    "url": "https://company.name",
                    "logo": {
                        "@type": "ImageObject",
                        "url": "https://company.name/logo.png"
                    },
                    "founder": "Founder",
                    "foundingDate": "2019"
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": "Article",
                "position": "2",
                "mainEntityOfPage": {
                    "@type": "WebPage",
                    "@id": "/gadgets-tech/meet-keysmart-the-smart-key-oraganiser/"
                },
                "articleSection": "Gadgets & Tech",
                "headline": "Meet Keysmart: The smart key organiser",
                "datePublished": "2019-09-01",
                "dateModified": "2019-09-01",
                "image": "/content/uploads/2019/08/the-smartkey-orgainser-001-800.jpg",
                "url": "/gadgets-tech/meet-keysmart-the-smart-key-oraganiser/",
                "author": "The Author",
                "publisher": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "Company Name",
                    "url": "https://company.name",
                    "logo": {
                        "@type": "ImageObject",
                        "url": "https://company.name/logo.png"
                    },
                    "founder": "Founder",
                    "foundingDate": "2019"
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
</script>
```

However, as mentioned above, this `ItemList` is only for the five 'Most Recent' articles. I would now like to add structured data for the other section, 'Most Popular', and not sure how best to approach it.

1. Do I add the most popular five articles to the same `ItemList`, do I
   create a new `ItemList` or do I create a new script/JSON? How is
   this best achieved? Please provide an example.
2. Do I really need to add publisher/organization for each article like
   I have or can this be shortened somehow? It seems unnecessarily
   bulky doing it as I have.
3. Each of these mini-articles points to a full article using
   `mainEntityOfPage`. Am I right using type 'WebPage' or should I be
   using type 'Article'?
4. If two lists are required, is there a way of telling search engines 
   that one list contains most recent items and one contains most 
   popular or is that unnecessary?

Comment: Why do you want to put the `ItemList` on each of them?   I'm not aware of any possible benefit of doing so.   The only benefit of schema is usually getting a rich snippet from Google.  Even if Google supports `ItemList` for a rich snippet (and I don't think they do), using it twice isn't going to help.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - Schema.org does offer `ItemList` https://schema.org/ItemList and Google does support it, and for Articles, https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel. Thanks, but I think I'll wait for somebody else that can advise more accurately.